# jQuery load() only executes for 1 line?

Tags: jquery, load, qliksense

The 2 load statements below. Only one of them will execute.. not sure why.

If I cross out the first load statement `Page2Box1QVObject`, then the second one will load fine. Which leads me to suspect only the first load runs.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
//Navigation #2
$(".Explore2").click(function() {
  //Page Boxes  
  $("#Page2").attr('class', 'Active');
  $("#Page1, #Page3,#Page4,#Page5,#Page6").attr('class', 'NonActive');

  //Load in the QV Objects on click
  $("#Page2 .Box1").load(IPDashApp.getObject('Page2Box1QVObject', 'fmhnJM'));
  $("#Page2 .Box2").load(IPDashApp.getObject('Page2Box2QVObject', 'zSAspS'));

  //Click Icon Boxes (Green Shadow)
  $(".Explore2").addClass('ActiveExplore');
  $(".Explore1, .Explore3, .Explore4, .Explore5, .Explore6").removeClass('ActiveExplore');
});
```

Comment: How are .Box1 and .Box2 related?

Comment: Check the Network tab in the console to see the requests and responses. Do you see them both?

Comment: Add callback functions that log to the console, to confirm that they're working.

Comment: You're not doing anything obviously wrong. There's nothing that would normally prevent multiple `.load()` calls from working.

Comment: Not sure how to embed images but this is the console error I get
https://ibb.co/haQNO9